# .bashrc file showing error

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am using linux mint 17.2 64bit rafaela cinnamon edition . I configured hadoop 2.7.1 successfully but after a system restart it is showing errors.
I have installed oracle jdk1.8. These are my hadoop's hduser .bashrc file values.

```
# Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on)

 # Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
 # --hadoop enviroment variable starts --#
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME = $HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/
# --hadoop enviroment variable end --#
```

And The version is

```
 Hadoop 2.7.1
 Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 
 15ecc87ccf4a0228f35af08fc56de536e6ce657a
 Compiled by jenkins on 2015-06-29T06:04Z
 Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
 From source with checksum fc0a1a23fc1868e4d5ee7fa2b28a58a
 This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common 
 /hadoop-   common-2.7.1.jar
```

while login to hduser the terminal shows error that shown below

```
Password: 
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/local/hadoop': not a valid identifier
```

I got every needed component at the first time i put 'jps' command but after OS restart the 'jps' command returns the following value only

```
hduser@vishnu-300E5E-300E4E-300E5V-300E4V ~ $jps
3727 Jps
hduser@vishnu-300E5E-300E4E-300E5V-300E4V ~ $
```

Let me know the configuration problem I am new to linux

Comment: Can you please upload the .bashrc file somewhere and post a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space at line 12: `export YARN_HOME = $HADOOP_HOME`.

```
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```

bash doesn't like spaces around `=`

If you want to know on which line number it failes next time, you can paste it in a text file and execute that file with `bash file.sh`
It'll tell you nicely where you need to look.

Comment: Thank you Ruben.. now i got the mistake.. thank you very much